# How to overlay multiple histograms with x y shift

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to overlay multiple histograms, and shift each one on x y axis. So far I am generating individual plots and using illustrator to design the final one, however I would like to do all in my script. Tried for a long time, and was not successful. I prepared a small text case. It does not make much sense for this dataset, but for my data it is a pretty good solution. Would be very happy if someone can help.
Thanks

Here is the sample code that generates overlaid histograms.

```
import random
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data1 = [random.gauss(3,2) for _ in range(400)]
data2 = [random.gauss(4,2) for _ in range(400)]
data3 = [random.gauss(5,2) for _ in range(400)]

bins = numpy.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 25)

plt.hist(data3, bins, label='data3')
plt.hist(data2, bins, label='data2')
plt.hist(data1, bins, label='data1')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.savefig("trial01.pdf", transparent=True)
```

[image: Overlaid Histograms]

However the figure I want is similar to that

[image: Expected Histogram Figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to shift the complete axes with its content. This would require to plot each histogram in its own axes, share the axes, and set the respective axes position (`ax.set_position`). You may then turn the ticks, spines and labels off where needed.

```
import random
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

data1 = [random.gauss(3,2) for _ in range(400)]
data2 = [random.gauss(4,2) for _ in range(400)]
data3 = [random.gauss(5,2) for _ in range(400)]

bins = numpy.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1, label="ax2")
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(111, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1, label="ax3")

ax1.set(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 25))

ax1.hist(data3, bins, label='data3', color="C2")
ax2.hist(data2, bins, label='data2', color="C1")
ax3.hist(data1, bins, label='data1', color="C0")
fig.legend(loc='upper right')


xshift=0.04; yshift=0.04
for i, ax in enumerate((ax3,ax2,ax1)):
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    pos = ax.get_position()
    newpos = Bbox.from_bounds(pos.x0+i*xshift, pos.y0+i*yshift, pos.width, pos.height)
    ax.set_position(newpos)
    for sp in ["top", "right"]:
        ax.spines[sp].set_visible(False)

    if ax != ax3:
        ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
        ax.tick_params(labelleft=False, left=False, labelbottom=False)

fig.savefig("trial01.pdf", transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I don't really get the difference between pyplot, and this "fig, ax" approach. The latter seems to be much more flexible.

Comment: Correct. It's always useful to store a handle to an object, such that you can later call its methods.